# Let $a,b\in D_4$ and such that $ba=a^{3}b$. Prove that if $0\leq i<4$ and $0\leq j<2$, then $a^ib^ja^{i_1}b^{j_1}=a^{i+3i_1}b^{j+j_1}$

Tags: group-theory, dihedral-groups

Let $a,b\in D_4$ and such that $ba=a^{3}b$. Prove that if $0\leq i<4$ and $0\leq j<2$, then $a^ib^ja^{i_1}b^{j_1}=a^{i+3i_1}b^{j+j_1}$,(where $i,j,i_1,j_1\in \mathbb{Z}$) also it is given $o(a)=4$ and $o(b)=2$. $D_4$ is a dihedral group of order $8$.

I could only verify the fact that if $ba=a^3b$, then $\forall i\in \mathbb {Z}$, $ba^i=a^{3i}b$. This is because $ba^i=baa^{i-1}=a^3ba^{i-1}=a^3baa^{i-2}=a^6ba^{i-2}$. Then, continuing on this way, we have, $a^{3i}b=ba^i$. But I dont know how to prove $a^ib^ja^{i_1}b^{j_1}=a^{i+3i_1}b^{j+j_1}$?

Comment: @DietrichBurde I have edited the question ...

Comment: Note: the [tag:proof-explanation] tag is for understanding a particular proof you already have.

Comment: @Shaun Ok! I will keep it in mind ... Can you please help me with the proof?..

Comment: @DietrichBurde I think the problem I posed needs some correction as $j$ can either be $0$ or $1$, if $j=0$, then according to this identity , $a^k=a^k$ and $ba^k=a^3b$ respectively, which is true of course.  But if $a^ib^ja^{i_1}b^{j_1}=a^{i+3i_1}b^{j+j_1}$ is true then $b^ja^{i_1}=a^{3i_1}b^{j}$ is true. But due to the identity in kabenyuk's solutiin it is a contradiction and hence, $b^ja^{i_1}=a^{3i_1}b^{j}$isn't true due to which $a^ib^ja^{i_1}b^{j_1}=a^{i+3i_1}b^{j+j_1}$isn't true either. What do you think ?...

Comment: I notice you deleted and re-asked the same question again. This is odd. It's a bit odder as your previous question received an answer. Your choice to delete and re-ask is unkind to your answerers and is not appropriate. I have merged that question into this one and migrated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If in a group $G$ for some elements $a,b$ the relation $ba=a^3b$ holds, then the equality
$$
b^ja^k=a^{3^jk}b^j\tag1
$$
is valid.
To prove this equality, you can reason like this:
$$
b^ja^k=b^{j-1}a^{3k}b=b^{j-2}a^{3^2k}b^2=\ldots.
$$
One can also use the fact that the mapping $x\to bxb^{-1}$ is an automorphism of the group $G$ to prove $(1)$.

If we additionally know that $a^4=1$, then equality $(1)$ turns into
$$
b^ja^k=a^{(-1)^jk}b^j.\tag2
$$
Finally, if we also know that $j=0$ or $j=1$, then we don't need either formula $(1)$ or formula $(2)$. We only need the formula
$$
ba^k=a^{-k}b.
$$

No one but you can tell exactly what your problem is. And only you can formulate it.

Comment: But how do you arrive at that identity $b^ja^k=a^{3^jk}b^j$ ?...

Comment: But $b^ja^k=b^{j-1}ba^k$. So, how is $b^{j-1}ba^k=b^{j-1}a^3b$? Wont it be $b^{j-1}ba^k=b^{j-1}a^{3k}b$?

Comment: Sorry, that's a typo, I corrected it.

Comment: I think the problem I posed needs some correction as j can either be 0 or 1, if j=0, then according to ur identity , $a^k=a^k$ and $ba^k=a^3b$ respectively, which is true of course.

Comment: What do you think? ...

Comment: @Arthur I have stated all my thoughts about it in the new version of my answer (since I dared to answer your question). I have nothing more to add.

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice conceptual approach to this using the fact that conjugation is au automorphism, and the map $G\to Aut(G)$ by $g\mapsto \phi_g$ where $\phi(g)(h)=ghg^{-1}$ is a homomorphism.

We can rewrite $ba=a^3b$ as $bab^{-1}=a^3$.  Then by the automorphism property, $ba^ib^{-1}=\phi_b(a^i)=\phi_b(a)^i=(a^3)^i=a^{3i}$.

Now, we can proceed inductively.  $\phi_{b^2}(a^i)=\phi_b(\phi_b(a^i))=\phi_b(a^{3i})=(a^3)^{3i}=a^{3^2i}$, and more generally, $phi_{b^j}(a^i)=a^{3^ji}$.

Multiplying by $b^j$, this shows that $b^ja^i=a^{i3^j}b^j$, which is slightly different than what the problem claims.

If you additionally have information about the order of $a$ and $b$, the results may simplify somewhat, but I still do not believe that the problem is correct as stated.

Comment: Thanks! But I am still learning about elementary group theory and I dont know about automorphisms...